# Pointer of base class vector, poiting to derived class vector

Tags: c++, class, pointers, polymorphism, stdvector

I almost choked on searching similar topics but didn't find the answer I was looking for.

Here my problem:

Given a base class T, there are several derived classes A, B, C, etc.

I have a set of vectors:

```
std::vector<A*> a;
std::vector<B*> b;
std::vector<C*> c;
```

(...)
and also

```
std::vector<T*> t;
```

During the run of my code, a,b,c... are filled out. Then I need to make an analysis that only depends on the base class members, but the user must choose which of a,b,c will be used.
So, I implemented it over the std::vector t and the first thing I do is just copy the user-selected vector to the vector of the base class.

```
i.e. outHit = std::vector<CbmPixelHit*>(tofHit.begin(),tofHit.end());
```

It works, but the vectors are quite large so becomes an expensive process.

What I am looking for is how to make:
std::vector<T*> *t_ptr to point to the selected vector;

Here what I tried :

```
std::vector<CbmStsHit*> stsHit;
std::vector<CbmTofHit*> tofHit;
std::vector<CbmPixelHit*> *outHit;
```

(...)

```
TString outDet = "ToF";
if (outDet.Contains("Tof")){
    outHit = &tofHit;
}
```

The base class is CbmPixelHit. CbmStsHit and CbmTofHit are derived class
But I got

> error: assigning to 'std::vector<CbmPixelHit *> *' from incompatible
> type 'std::vector<CbmTofHit *> *'
> outHit = &tofHit;

What is the proper way to solve this?

Comment: You can't do that; it isn't type safe. It would allow you to `outHit = &tofHit; (*outHit)[0] = new CbmStsHit;`, which nobody wants.

Comment: The assignment operator does not exist, because two vectors never manage the same storage.
A move assignment operator (`outHit = std::move(tofHit);` assuming you don't need tofHit afterwards) would be possible, but does not exist either.
I would suggest making the part of your code that deals with `outHit` a template or auto lambda that can deal with the vectors of pointers to derived types as well.

Comment: How big are the vectors that converting a bunch of pointers and copying them becomes too expensive?

Comment: the size of the vectors is in the order of 1e+9. But in principle could be larger: up to 1e+12.

Comment: Are you sure about these magnitudes? A vector of size 1e12 would consume eight contiguous *tera*bytes just for the pointers, and then you have the objects on top of that. Do you really have that much memory? (Even with 1e9 elements, multiple blocks of eight contiguous gigabytes each is optimistic on a regular desktop machine.) Also, at one nanosecond per allocation, which is *very* optimistic, just the dynamic allocation of 1e12 objects would take over fifteen minutes.

Comment: One of the ongoing tasks is to reduce that memory usage. Currently, I manage to go in the order of 1e+9.
To test purpose the size is about 1e+6. But not less.
Unfortunately, yes, I am sure about that number